# Two player betting system that converges net gain to zero in the long run

Tags: probability, random-walk, gambling

Let's say there are two friends A and B and they want to regularly play a non-drawable (one party always wins) competitive game (e.g. US 8-balls) with each other with bets. Every time a player wins, the losing player has to pay some non-zero amount X to the other. In order to simplify things, assume that player A has a winning probability of Pa

Find a system to calculate X (it can depend upon the past win/loss history of the player) for each game, such that, in the long run, net gain of both players converge to zero (i.e. the total money they have lost and won are close to equal).

What doesn't work:
When Pa = 0.5, and X = $1 (always), the net money won is equivalent to the position of a symmetric random walk, and it doesn't converge to zero.

Can such a betting system exist? (Except for a trivial case of X=0).

The motivation here is that it should be possible to win money in the short term, but in long term, it has to converge to zero.

Comment: You better have $Pa=\frac 12$ or there will be a bias away from $0$ that you can't overcome

Comment: @RossMillikan X can be biased too, to correct for the bias in Pa. What I mean is, X can be defined as something like: X = f(Pa) when A wins, and X = g(Pa) when B wins.

Comment: @rajendra Given your random walk example, assuming $P_a = 0.5$, the net money won will *never* converge if X is a constant, you have already explained why. Unless you let X be defined also in terms of time, defining it in terms of $P_a$ or $P_b$ still results in a constant X for any given scenario. The only possible outcome is an X of zero, which defeats the purpose of the game.

Comment: @Gabe X doesn't have to be constant, and it doesn't need to be defined only in terms of Pa or Pb.

Comment: @rajendra Can you give me an example of X that is allowed to be defined for a specific example? Say, $P_a=0.4$

Comment: @Gabe $X_b= totalwins_a - totalloss_a$
This doesn't work, obviously, but just giving an example.